# viewstate value error senting post data by curl android

Tags: android, asp.net, curl, viewstate

iam a user of a aspx website ,i recently made a shell script to download a pdf file from the website,the script work very fine 2-3 days..however it stops working after that...the error was 'viewstate validation' error .iam a complete noob in shell programming..
Viewstate value i captured by using curl command:

/wEPDwUJOTcyNDMyNDExZGTFH+8YURsFdHWIPx+4glo2ovFz2w==

Viewstate value i posted using curl command :

/wEPDwUJOTcyNDMyNDExZGTFH+8YURsFdHWIPx+4glo2ovFz2w==

Viewstate value error shown by the aspx webpage:

/wEPDwUJOTcyNDMyNDExZGTFH 8YURsFdHWIPx 4glo2ovFz2w==

As you can see the viewstate value shown by the error page doesnt contain '+' symbol,is this could be the reason for the viewstate validation error?
But i post the data correctly by using curl command..bt i dont know why the error page shows an incorrect viewstate value.any help could be much appreciated
Can the webserver blocked the curl request? Because i used the curl command too often
So i changed the user agent and ip address still showing viewstate error webpage

Answer (score 0):

Instead of auto-generating the validation keys which is the default in ASP.Net  specify them  explicitly as shown below. These keys are used to validate view state.

Also, in your aspx page try adding these to Page directive at top of your page: `ViewStateEncryptionMode="Never" EnableViewStateMac="false"`.

Generate your own keys explicitly since its a security feature by using IIS Manager as explained at this URL: [Generate Keys in IIS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vijaysk/2009/05/13/iis-7-tip-10-you-can-generate-machine-keys-from-the-iis-manager/)

```
<system.web>
<machineKey  
validationKey="21F090935F6E49C2C797F69BBAAD8402ABD2EE0B667A8B44EA7DD4374267A75D7
               AD972A119482D15A4127461DB1DC347C1A63AE5F1CCFAACFF1B72A7F0A281B"           
decryptionKey="ABAA84D7EC4BB56D75D217CECFFB9628809BDB8BF91CFCD64568A145BE59719F"
validation="SHA1"
decryption="AES"
/>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Bro im just a user of the website not an admin..so i cant edit the source

Comment: What could be the reason for my shell script to stop working all in a sudden after all it works very fine 3 days..

Comment: May be your script changed the viewstate. ViewState has a `very strong` security built around it and ASP.Net framework will catch even the slightest tampering with it.

Comment: IS there any way to unblock the curl request?